# Loading View From XIB and getting nil macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

I am trying to load a view from a xib file. What I am looking to do seems pretty simple to me but for some reason it is much more difficult than I thought it would be. I simply have a custom view (with labels, buttons and tableviews) that I want to reuse multiple times in the same window (in a stack view). Here is my code for the custom view

```
class PlatformView: NSView {
    @IBOutlet var testLabel: NSTextField!

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.testLabel.stringValue = "Init"
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }
}
```

Here is my view in the view did load of the main View Controller. I am doing it twice because I need two of the same view in the stack view. The problem is that I am getting an error. This line is nil `let topLevelObjects = objectArray2?.firstObject as? PlatformView` and is causing a lot of issues. This only happens sometimes when I run the app. It is pretty random and I don't know why it is happening. Is there a better way to do this? Or am I doing something wrong in my code?

```
var objectArray:NSArray?
guard let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "PlatformView"), bundle: nil) else {return}
if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &objectArray), let topLevelObjects = objectArray?.firstObject as? PlatformView {
    self.platformStackView.addArrangedSubview(topLevelObjects)
    self.firstPlatformView = topLevelObjects
}

if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &objectArray), let topLevelObjects = objectArray?.firstObject as? PlatformView {
    self.platformStackView.addArrangedSubview(topLevelObjects)
    self.secondPlatformView = topLevelObjects
}
```

Comment: You can't guarantee that the firstObject is the PlatformView you are looking for.  There can be multiple top level objects so you should check them all for the PlatformView you want.  In my testing I had only one view in the XIB file (with sub views) but the interface builder had also added something else I needed to ignore.  In my test the top level objects were my TestView and an instance of NSApplication.  I had to check the array to get TestView which was the second item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instantiate returns an array of top level objects in the XIB file some of which interface builder itself may have added (see the layout of a XIB if you are really curious about it).

The simple manner is to search the returned topLevelObjects for your PlatformView like this:

```
if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &objectArray) {
    for object in topLevelObjects {
        if let platformView = object as? PlatformView {
            self.platformStackView.addArrangedSubview(platformView)
            self.firstPlatformView = platformView
        }
    }
}
```

However assuming you are sure your PlatformView is in the XIB a more elegant solution is something like this:

```
if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &objectArray) {
    if let topLevelObjects = objectArray {
        let platformView = topLevelObjects.flatMap({ object in return object as? PlatformView }).first!
        self.platformStackView.addArrangedSubview(platformView)
        self.firstPlatformView = platformView
    }
}
```

As I say you have to be careful there because of the force unwrapping of an optional.

Comment: what is `topLevelObjects` referring to before the flatmap? If you meant to put `objectArray` that is also not working. The first method seems to work initially when I am trying it but if there is a more elegant solution, I would much rather use that.

Comment: Sorry.  I have updated my example as I had unwrapped the optional objectArray into a definitive array for usage.